# Why am I getting a server error from the Firebase dynamic links API?

Tags: ruby, rest, firebase, google-api, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to create a managed dynamic link using the Firebase API and the [google-api-client Ruby gem](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client). Here's the code I'm using, complete with an inline Gemfile for easier testing:

```ruby
require 'bundler/inline'

gemfile(true) do
  gem 'google-api-client', '~> 0.20'
end

require 'google/apis/firebasedynamiclinks_v1'
require 'cgi'

include Google::Apis::FirebasedynamiclinksV1

service = FirebaseDynamicLinksService.new.tap do |service|
  service.authorization = Google::Auth::DefaultCredentials.make_creds(
    json_key_io: File.open('path/to/auth.json'),
    scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase']
  )

  # do this until https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/652
  # is fixed
  service.instance_variable_set(
    :@root_url, 'https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/'
  )
end

link = CGI.escape('http://example.com')

request = CreateManagedShortLinkRequest.new(
  long_dynamic_link: "https://f4w25.app.goo.gl/?link=#{link}&ibi=com.foo.bar",
  name: 'Test test'
)

service.create_managed_short_link(request)
```

This script errors with `Server error (Google::Apis::ServerError)`. The body of the response is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Internal error encountered.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "backendError"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to dump out the raw request that is being sent (ideally URL, headers and request body, though feel free to scrub auth header!)?

Comment: Also, looking at the docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener) we don't highlight "name" - can you see if just passing the longDynamicLink helps?

Comment: @IanBarber sadly removing the `name` parameter results in `badRequest: Request contains an invalid argument.` (which doesn't make sense to me). It appears the `v1/managedShortLinks:create` endpoint isn't documented, but it _is_ mentioned in the service discovery document. I'll work on getting a raw request.

Comment: Michael's answer below is right (he works on Dynamic Links directly)! The managedshortlink API isn't currently available (though it is in the API, we don't document it), hence the error.

Comment: Ah ok, I wondered about that. Is there any way to create a dynamic link that shows up in the Firebase console then?

Comment: There is not right now, sorry - we're looking into getting that exposed (as you found), but nothing usable right now.

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. If you can share, any idea when that API will be ready?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170802/discussion-between-cameron-and-ian-barber).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Please use `CreateShortDynamicLinkRequest` instead of `CreateManagedShortLinkRequest`.

Comment: Unfortunately `CreateShortDynamicLinkRequest` uses the `shortLink` endpoint, which doesn't create a managed link and therefore doesn't show up in the Firebase console. I assume that's why it doesn't accept a `name` parameter either, since names are only useful for managed links.

Comment: Sadly because the managed link API isn't ready yet, this is the correct answer. Thanks @michael-hermanto.

Comment: Anything new about exposing the managed short links API? We would like to create URLs with custom suffix via REST API. Thanks.

Comment: They're not interchangeable though, I'd love the ability to create a link with custom_suffix via REST API.

Comment: Still waiting for the managedShortLinks to be exposed correctly #askFirebase