# Getting server error on firebase dynamic link CreateManagedShortLinkRequest with the Ruby client

Tags: firebase, google-api, firebase-dynamic-links, google-api-ruby-client

I am trying to create a dynamic link using the Ruby SDK. I believe I have everything right, but I'm getting a

> Google::Apis::ServerError: Server error

When creating the URL

Could you help me figure out what I'm missing/doing wrong or if this is a Google issue ?

Assuming I have generates Oauth credentials requesting the appropriate scopes, I am doing

```rb
request = ::Google::Apis::FirebasedynamiclinksV1::CreateManagedShortLinkRequest.new(
  dynamic_link_info: ::Google::Apis::FirebasedynamiclinksV1::DynamicLinkInfo.new(
    domain_uri_prefix: Rails.application.secrets.firebase_dynamic_link_prefix,
    link: campaign.linkedin_url,
  ),
  suffix: ::Google::Apis::FirebasedynamiclinksV1::Suffix.new(
    option: 'SHORT',
  ),
  # name: "Linkedin acquisition URL of #{camp.utm_campaign_name} for #{camp.contractor.name} <#{camp.contractor.email}>",
  name: "Test of generation",
)
# => <Google::Apis::FirebasedynamiclinksV1::CreateManagedShortLinkRequest:0x000021618baa88 
#   @dynamic_link_info=#<Google::Apis::FirebasedynamiclinksV1::DynamicLinkInfo:0x000021618bad80 
#     @domain_uri_prefix="https://example.page.link", 
#     @link="https://www.example.com/?invitation_code=example&signup=example&utm_campaign=example&utm_medium=example&utm_source=example">, 
#   @name="Test of generation", 
#   @suffix=#<Google::Apis::FirebasedynamiclinksV1::Suffix:0x000021618babf0 
#     @option="SHORT">
# >
link_service.create_managed_short_link(request)

def link_service
  @link_service ||= begin
    svc = ::Google::Apis::FirebasedynamiclinksV1::FirebaseDynamicLinksService.new
    svc.authorization = oauth_service.credentials
    svc
  end
end
```

I know OAuth scopes seem to be working as previously I was getting

> Google::Apis::ClientError: forbidden: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

But I fixed it after increasing OAuth scopes to cover firebase. Also, my request seems correct, as when I try to omit one of the parameters (like the `name`) I'm getting appropriate validation errors like

> Google::Apis::ClientError: badRequest: Created Managed Dynamic Link must have a name

My only clue, is that the `create_managed_short_link` actually takes more parameters. In the example given above, I also have substituted our real firebase prefix by `example` but I do own the real firebase prefix I am using, and link generation directly from the Firebase frontend console actually works.

I've updates my google sdk to the most recent version up to date
- `google-api-client-0.30.3`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately generating managed short links through the REST API is not currently supported.

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50261812/why-am-i-getting-a-server-error-from-the-firebase-dynamic-links-api) by someone who works(ed) in the dynamic links team itself.

For now we can only use `CreateShortDynamicLinkRequest`, however this endpoint does not allow to specify a `custom_suffix` (i.e. https://example.com/my-custom-suffix)